# We can't load the requested web page on event registration page

Tags: civievent

Getting '**We can't load the requested web page**' error when some one first accessing event registration page if language parameter(lcMessages) included in the URL.
I checked the session values, qfPrivateKey and qfSessionID not set to the session,so **key** validate failed on page submit, Also **$_SESSION['CiviCRM']** having only lcMessages no other values.
Added print statement in set() function in *CRM\Core\Session.php* to print $_SESSION but added value not there in session.

> $session[$name] = $value;
>         
>  print_r($_SESSION);

CiviCRM: 4.6.2, Drupal: 7.44

Comment: Does this problem happen on newer versions? lcMessages code was changed up quite a bit on Civi 4.7, so the answer is probably to try upgrading a test site.

Comment: Thanks!. I didn't update my code to latest version, checked the file difference between my version and Civi 4.7.3 but not much difference at file(ConfigSetting.php, Session.php) level.